# Can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 on 2 hard drives?

Tags: dual-boot

Can I dual-boot Windows 10 Technical Preview and Ubuntu 14.04 on 2 hard drives, 1 SATA built into my PC and one portable HDD. I want to but I am scared it won't work.

Here are my specifications:

```
AMD Quad Core CPU E2-6110 (1.50 GHz)
AMD Radeon R2 Graphics
4 GB DDR3 L Memory
500 GB HDD
Portable Hard Drive is 1TB
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows first and Ubuntu second. Ubuntu will install a bootloader automatically. If you have two hard drives, you can choose on which to install the bootloader during installation of Ubuntu. Make sure to boot from this one. You can choose which hard drive to boot from in the bios settings.

Comment: But will it work with Windows 10? I heard it doesn't.

Comment: If Windows is not detected, you can use [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If you want to be able to go back to only Windows, first boot the live system (click "Try Ubuntu"), open GParted and organize your partitions as you want them. Make a ext4 partition and a linux-swap partition. If you got that and applied it, remember the name of your hdd/ssd (usually /dev/sda), close GParted, connect a data storage device and open a terminal. Then enter this command to back up your MBR: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/destination bs=512 count=1` (possibly replace /dev/sda)

Answer (score 0):

It will actually, Because I have Windows 10 Build 9926 and my trusty Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I recommend you should cut some of your NTFS Partition and splice it more for `/`,`/home` and `efi` partitions using either GParted or others.