# Ubuntu - Windows 10 dual boot problem, can't boot Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I wanted to use dual boot, but didn't have enough space on my `C:` drive to do so. So I  bought an SSD (on Windows `E:\`) and here as `sda2/sda3` and tried to install it there following the guide from this question.

[Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

I do not have a GRUB menu screen when starting the computer and second because of that, I cannot boot into my Windows OS.

```
Medium /dev/sda: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 Bytes, 1465149168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: dos
Medienkennung: 0xf9f466ac

Gerät      Boot      Start       Ende   Sektoren  Größe Id Typ
/dev/sda1             2048 1338822655 1338820608 638,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       1338822656 1340092415    1269760   620M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3  *    1340092416 1465147391  125054976  59,6G 83 Linux


Medium /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 Bytes, 1953525168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: dos
Medienkennung: 0x8599553d

Gerät      Boot Start       Ende   Sektoren  Größe Id Typ
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Medium /dev/sdc: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 Bytes, 488397168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: dos
Medienkennung: 0x626f7671

Gerät      Boot     Start      Ende  Sektoren Größe Id Typ
/dev/sdc1            2048   1026047   1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2  *      1026048 487425945 486399898  232G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3       487426048 488390655    964608  471M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

#### Is there any way I can add my Windows bootloader to GRUB?

I think I might have found the issue but reading the other post and trying the answers did not help. `/dev/sda3/` and `/dev/sdc2/` are marked as boot as far as I understood. `/dev/sdc2` is my Windows home drive, while `/dev/sdc1` is the actual boot loader and for Linux `/dev/sda3` is the root folder and `/dev/sda2` the supposed to be boot loader.

[Boot info script summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zTpJ2SvxWt/)

**The first answer of the linked post**
I have made it work somewhat, but when restarting after having added the custom.cfg to the `/boot/grub/` I get the following Error:

```
no such device:/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: @karel it would be nice if you could check my post again, I think I might have found the issue but reading the other post and trying the answers did not help. **dev/sda3/ and dev/sdc2/ are marked as boot as far as I understood.** sdc2 is my windows home drive while sdc1 is the actual boot loader and for linux sda3 is the root folder and sda2 the supposed to be boot loader

Comment: Win 10 on a  DOS partitioned disk = legacy.  You installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode.  Check your UEFI settings(BIOS) for the mode preference selection, and change it to boot the install media in legacy (it has both, and boots UEFI now).

Comment: @ubfan1 so after changing that, do I have to reinstall ubuntu or will everything work then?

Comment: You might get working by just reinstalling grub-pc (the legacy one), there are few differences between the intstalls other than the bootloaders, but a reinstall might be easier.

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks for your help mate I will try it in about an hour! I wish I could mark your comment as answer