# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install failed from DVD-R

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Can Ubuntu 18.04 LTS be installed on a Windows 10x64 bit laptop with an Intel core i3 CPU?

Have already tried this by downloading software and burning on to a DVD but it would not boot up and an error message shows an incompatible format being used was the problem.

How can I rectify this? Do I need to format another DVD R disk before burning the ISO download or will I have to download a different ISO from the original?

Hope you can help.

Thanks
Bill

Comment: Did you verify your download? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) then verify the write to install-media (dvdr) using the 'check disc for defects' option (disc in this case means install media be it cdr/dvdr/dvdrw/thumb-drive/..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) - you must follow the install instructions carefully, or it won't work. "Incompatible format" usually indicates a common didn't-follow-the-instructions mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In order to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in the most painless way possible, have a look at this question [Link for question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031993/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows-10)

Also, you can Download the ISO from http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ 
For writing the data to a DVD-R/USB i would recommend you try this tool https://rufus.ie/

I recommend that instead of writing it to a DVD-R,you should write it to a USB drive as it would be easier to format and create a new Bootable disk if required.

If you have any more questions I'd be happy to help

Answer (score 1):

1 "*Can Ubuntu 18.04 LTS be installed on a Windows 10x64 bit laptop with an Intel core i3 CPU?*"  Almost certainly.

2 "*Have already tried this by downloading software and burning on to a DVD but it would not boot up and an error message shows an incompatible format being used was the problem*." Sounds like the DVD-R already had something on it when you tried to add the ISO file to the DVD-R.  DVD-R discs can receive multiple writes, but not if you're trying to make them bootable with an ISO. DVD-Rs are a pain to work with; an inexpensive USB flash drive is much easier to set up, especially with the Windows program [Rufus](https://rufus.ie).

3 "*Do I need to format another DVD R disk before burning the ISO download or will I have to download a different ISO from the original?*" You don't format a DVD-R before putting the ISO on it; the ISO has to be burned onto an absolutely virgin disc, following [these instructions from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

Here's a current download of [Ubuntu's 18.04.3 ISO file](http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-iso/18.04.3/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) and the SHA256 file used to verify the [ISO was not corrupted in the download process](http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-iso/18.04.3/SHA256SUMS) using [Microsoft's free FCIV utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290/availability-and-description-of-the-file-checksum-integrity-verifier-u).