# Ubuntu doesn't detect windows 10 while installing

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I would like to install ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS alongside windows 10 (preinstalled in my laptop with UEFI).
I followed several guides, which lead me at this point. I had:

- Create a partition of about 16GB (still not allocated)
- Disable fastboot and secureboot from UEFI
- Disable fastrestart from windows settings
- Ensure that Ubuntu is running in EFI checking at /sys/firmware/efi

After all this steps, Ubuntu still not show "Install alongside windows" option while installing.
What should I do?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted --list
Model: ATA ST2000LM015-2E81 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      16.8MB  2000GB  2000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 62.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  62.1GB  62.1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

**SOLVED**

The problem was that Ubuntu didn't see SSD at all, not only the existing OS.
Solved switching SATA from EDI to AHCI.

Comment: Please add `sudo parted --list`to your question. ensure, that windows 10 is completed shutdown.

Comment: @nobody, thank for the answer. Screenshot added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031993/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows-10)

Comment: @user68186 sorry Im new on forums. updated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv) for information about Windows **dynamic** partition. If you have this kind of partitions for windows, Ubuntu won't detect it.

Comment: @Marco Sodano Have you got the 'Something Else' option for installing Ubuntu?

Comment: What brand/model system? Many require both UEFI update & SSD firmware update.

Comment: @PaulBenson yes, but SSD disk is not showed.

Comment: @oldfred It's an Asus Tuf fx505ge

Comment: Many Asus need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. And may need acpi=off boot parameter and if nVidia nomodeset boot parameter also, until nVidia driver installed from Ubuntu repository (not from nVidia).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when I was installing my Ubuntu 19.04 for the 1st time alongside my Windows 10. The only guide that helped me was this one:

https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/

Now I've just upgraded to 19.10 and everything is working just fine alongside my Windows 10.

But before doing anything make sure you have these steps covered 1st:

1- Check that you have less than 4 partitions if it's in MBR format (Master Boot Record), including system reserved, in order to be able to choose your free space in the installation phase.

To check whether your HD is MBR or GPT follow these steps:

You can check you HD on Windows 10 by pressing the "Windows Key+R" to open the Run dialog, type “diskmgmt.msc” into the box, and press Enter.

Locate your Main HD, it should be indicated as disk 1 as shown below and right-click on it and choose "properties":

[Finding your main HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWRSy.png)

You will see this image:

[HD Properties find Partition style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USlDU.png)

If it's MBR then make sure that you have at least 2 partitions plus your system reserved which makes them 3 in total. Otherwise, the Ubuntu installation will not recognize the free space and will display it as Unallocated space and will be un-clickable.

If it's in GPT then you're good to go.

2- I recommend giving Ubuntu more than 16 GB as the minimum recommended space is 19 GB. But I personally recommend more than that, I gave mine 50 GB of free space. Why is that? The more you get used to Linux the more you'll start using it more and more as your main daily OS and that forces you to install more apps and use up space in creating new projects and tasks. A 16 GB partition will be eaten up fast as soon as you start falling in love, Which you WILL, with LINUX Ubuntu.

3- Make sure to boot Windows 10 first after a successful installation to check whether everything inside Windows is intact and working fine, then you restart and boot Ubuntu for the 1st time.

4- Make sure to get the latest updates and upgrades after a successful installation by opening the terminal `ctrl + t` and running the following:

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If you decided to upgrade later on to the latest Ubuntu 19.10 version, follow the instructions in this blog:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-19-10-eoan-ermine

Sorry for making it long but it's a delicate process and 1 wrong step might fry your HD or break your windows. So I had to make sure to cover every single issue I personally faced when installing both Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.

Comment: Checked, it's a GPT disk. Don't now why Ubuntu does not detect it

Comment: Did you try burning the Ubuntu image on a USB drive using Rufus?

Comment: Yes, I used Rufus to create the bootable usb

Comment: Try this, it helped a friend of mine solve the same issue:

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-ubuntu-not-detecting-windows-10-partition-during-install/

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to dual boot.This does not seems to be common as you are telling,
I suggest you first run ubuntu in live mode then do partition using g-parted software hope this will be much safe.

Comment: As I could verify with sudo parted --list, ubuntu does not detect SSD. Therefor neither G-parted does