# Problem with installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I wanted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. My ASUS FX553VD-DM234T laptop has a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD.

First of all, I made a clean installation of Windows 10 (booted from an USB to do so; not that built-in "reset") and deleted all partitions as soon as I had the chance to (so I got left 2 drives with 100% unallocated space each). I installed windows 10 on the SSD.

Then I created a 800GB partition on the HDD with Windows' built-in tool. 200GB unallocated space left.

Now I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives) guide (seemed to be the one I needed) step by step and I'm certain I didn't forget anything or got anything wrong.

**And here's where I'm stuck now:** as soon as the installation is done and I can click the "restart now" button, the computer freezes. What I did then (after several minutes waiting) was to force the computer to shutdown (pressing the power button) and try starting it up again and pick Ubuntu where I can chose between this and Windows. It's the same problem, it freezes during the loading screen (if it even gets until there, that is).

I couldn't find any solution, and I'm starting to get pretty frustrated after the third try now.

I don't know if this image helps.

[image]

I just thought it seems strange that both show the same drive (the SSD), even though I definitely installed Ubuntu on the HDD only.

Comment: P.S. The boot option both being on the same disk is normal as Ubuntu will *boot* off the EFI partition which is always on the first disk, but then load it's OS files from the HDD.  (you have the problem mentioned in the duplicate question)