# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on separate hard drive a Windows 10 1809 but cannot create EFI partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but it crashes at the start.

I suspect that I do not have a 1st partition /EFI

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition
but these may not be uptodate?

I have tried to follow the instructions

[Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

```
1st Partition / EFI

    Select your target drive (in my case /dev/sdc)
    Select "Make New Partition Table"
    Partition the target drive as follows:
        Size: 650 MB
        Type for the new partition: Primary
        Location for the new partition: Beginning of this space
        Use as: EFI (this will be listed as /dev/sdc1 efi in the partitioning tool once you create it)
```

from my target drive /dev/sdd, but when I get to the use-as stage EFI is not listed.  Is Reserved for BIOS the right option here?

The result of this was a screen full of systemy errors that I was unable to capture.  I have now used gparted from the USB install to try to set up all 4 partitions, but have not found an option EPI System partition. Is my gparted too old?  It appears to install OK.

On booting I am now rewarded with a single unresponsive winking cursor :-(

I have some camera screen shots but have yet to find how to add to this post.

/dev/sdd
/dev/sdd1 16 MB 
/dev/sdd2 fat32
/dev/sdd3  ext4
/dev/sdd4  swap  mount /  50 GB
/dev/sdd5  ext4 mount /home

device for boost loader installation /dev/sdd2 (should this be /dev/sdd?)

/dev/ssd2 fath32 680 MB  EFI 
/

Comment: What do you mean by "It crashes"?

Comment: No, reserved BIOS boot area is not correct, should be EFI System Partiton

Comment: My first time produced a screen full of systemy message that I was unable to capture.

Comment: is uefi required ?    why not install both in bios mode ?

Comment: "The major difference between the two is that MBR uses 32-bit entries in its table which limits the total physical partitons to only 4. Each partition can only be a maximum of 2TB in size"

Comment: The underlying point here is that a 'legacy' install on both OS's would be less of a headache, if it is possible, as noted above. Otherwise it appears that the code you entered above is tagged wrong

Type for the new partition: Primary

should be 

Type for the new partition: Boot

Also noted to use FAT32

Lastly there is a difference in doing this if your running 32 bit OS's vrs 64 bit OS's - If 32 bit the process is not as straight forward

Comment: Thanks to all those answers.  I am struggling with an intermitent hardware failure at present, but will return to this when I have fixed it.  I really do want to only use UEFI as I have two large 4Tbyte disks and everything *should* work better with the UEFI GPT.