# 18.04.2 LTS dual boot with Win 10 Pro is causing Windows corruption

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm trying to dual boot a new Dell OptiPlex 5060 Micro.  I've setup it up multiple times with various configurations (typically start with Win10 install, boot, shrink partition, then install Ubuntu with defaults; did try Ubuntu install 1st, same same) but get Win10 corruption every time when using SATA III interface (I've tried Seagate 2.5” HDD 500GB, Samsung 860 EVO SSD 250GB and WD Blue SSD 1TB drive, same error with all).  Once I install and use Ubuntu and switch back to Win10, Win10 will not load, either blue screens with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR or will not load at all (black screen, video lost and never recovers).  Even if I can repair Win10, it happens again once Ubuntu is loaded.  Tried just for grins Samsung 850 EVO M.2 SSD 250GB, same dual boot setup, it worked fine (always partitioning single drive, splitting drive approximately in half for each OS).  So is this a software problem (I am assuming not because M.2 interface worked, and SATA III didn't), or a BIOS (UEFI) problem/error (running latest available), or hardware problem (bad).  I just cannot understand why Windows Boot Manager or disk partition is getting corrupted by running Linux instance but apparently only when running drive from SATA III interface but works fine with M.2 interface.

Comment: It sounds as though there is some corruption occurring when running Linux.  I have seen this occurring when Windows is using Intel's RST (rapid storage technology) which uses a small (16gb) SSD as a disk cache in Windows.  Some Linux users have tried installing installing Linux on that small SSD which corrupts Window's "disk cache".    I'm not saying this is your problem, but it may give you a direction to look that you perhaps haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I install Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04.2 in separate SSDs successfully. I make it done follow this link:[Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

Plus：if you have RTX2080TI installed, remember, unplug the card first. After installing the newest driver 415 then plug the card.