# Installed Ubuntu 19.04 - Dual Monitor Not Detected + Fan running Constantly

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, fan

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives). I installed with secure boot and installed the third party drivers "using the password" option. I looked under drivers and saw that it is using the newest nvidia driver 418, recommended and tested.

On boot in to Ubuntu, the following happens:

1. My 2nd monitor doesn't show up. Under display settings only one monitor is show and the other one is black
2. My fan is constantly running at high speed.

### Below are my system specs

System Information

---

Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit

System Model: OMEN by HP Obelisk Desktop 875-0xxx

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz (12 CPUs), ~3.2GHz

Memory: 16GB RAM

Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

---

Sound Devices

---

Description: Speaker/Headphone (Realtek(R) Audio)

Description: VX2453 Series (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)

Comment: woah so I just to play around I turned off secure boot, it booted right up and everything is working fine now !!

there still has to be a way to work this with secure boot right ?

Comment: Interesting. I have the same problem with my gs65. To make it more interesting, secure boot is already disabled, but still no result.