# Dual boot loading into Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi

I'm a beginner so bear with me. I had my laptop come with OEM Windows 10 UEFI/GPT (whatever that is). I read online that I need to install Ubuntu according to UEFI not MBR, so I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/843649/483763). I had my Windows 10 installed on the SSD with it's own EFI, Recovery, OS partitions. I installed Ubuntu on the HDD with EFI, Swap, /, /home partitions. After it's done installing I reboot and it boots to windows. I tried installing grub it's not working. I tried changing boot priority but only Windows shows up there. I tried `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`. That also didn't work. 
Please help me out! I natively work on Mac tho.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!
If I understand correctly, you have two separate physical disks, a SSD with Win10, and a spindle HDD with Ubuntu. Each disk has a EFI partition.

This is what I think your setup looks like:
SSD 0 - Windows 10 : EFI, Recovery part, C drive, other system partitions
HDD 1 - Ubuntu : EFI, /, /home, linux swap

In this setup, all you should have to do is configure your UEFI to use the spindle HDD 1 as the first boot device. This should boot the system to a GRUB2 prompt where you can choose to boot Windows 10, or GRUB2 will default boot Ubuntu after a few seconds.
This works this way because each disk has a separate EFI partition. If the UEFI is set to boot to the SSD 0, then the system will boot to Windows 10 like it always has because Windows 10 wouldn't be "aware" of Ubuntu on the HDD.
If you select HDD 1 as the boot device in UEFI and you still don't get Ubuntu, then there's probably something wrong with the install of Ubuntu and you should re-install it. A default install should be fine, just make sure it's using the HDD as the install location. If you need a separate /home partition and Linux SWAP partition, then using the custom partition option is the way to go.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! Yes my setup is exactly like above. Okay I get what you're saying. In UEFI menu I only get my SSD as boot priority. But I'm able to boot into grub by selecting the HDD as boot from boot menu option. I will try again in the morning and let installer install it alongside windows itself, rather than me modifying through the disk utility. I'll get back if it doesn't works. Thanks!

Comment: I can think of two options if we can’t set the HDD to have priority. Option 1: Install Ubuntu on HDD and point to the EFI on SSD during install. This should work, but Windows 10 upgrade may “fix” the EFI and you would have to repair the Ubuntu boot. Also, removing Ubuntu would require repairing the EFI so it boots Windows. Option 2: wipe both drives, then install Windows on the HDD. Afterwards, install Ubuntu on the SSD.

Comment: I'm not sure how to perform the option 1. But option 2 won't be helpful, I want my windows on SSD not HDD. Right now I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: look for a drop down selection named “device for boot loader installation” and make sure it’s pointing to the SSD drive. You may have to select the custom partitions option. This image shows the drop down I’m referring to (at the bottom): https://images.app.goo.gl/yKUUdt6hh9zALtgT8