# Grub only boots windows after I open my bios first

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 19.04

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10 pro. I have a m2 ssd with windows on it and a normal ssd with ubuntu on it. Both OS work fine.

When I try to boot windows with grub I get this error:

```
error: no such device: 6E4E-A0AB
error: file `/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found
```

If I then restart my pc and first open the bios and then exit again, I can choose windows in grub and this time I dont get the errors and it boots windows fine. If I then shut my pc down or restart and try to boot in to windows again I get the same error.

I can boot in to Ubuntu just fine no problems with that.

`sudo os-prober` in ubuntu shows:

```
 dev/nvme0n1p2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

`sudo update-grub` shows:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Can anyone help me resolve my grub problem with windows. Both OS run in uefi mode. I first had Ubuntu installed than disconnected that ssd and than installed windows on the m2 ssd btw. Dont know if that is something.

I would be very thankfull if someone can help me with this.

Edit: fstab output

````
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=89ca9766-ca28-4f94-afe2-2c65ad3dd0ef /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=26ED-3C0D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile```

lsblk output:

```NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL      UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                  
├─sda1      vfat                26ED-3C0D                            /boot/efi
└─sda2      ext4                89ca9766-ca28-4f94-afe2-2c65ad3dd0ef /
nvme0n1                                                              
└─nvme0n1p1 ntfs     Everything B2B88650B88612D1                     
nvme1n1                                                              
├─nvme1n1p1 ntfs     Recovery   0CF84E6AF84E51DE                     
├─nvme1n1p2 vfat                6E4E-A0AB                            
├─nvme1n1p3                                                          
└─nvme1n1p4 ntfs                76B8511AB850DA67```
````

Comment: When installing Windows after Ubuntu, you run `sudo-update grub` and it should work.  But grub only boots working Windows, and that includes that Windows fast start up must be off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Also many have needed UEFI updates and SSD firmware updates. You may want to confirm that UUID of FAT32 partition ESP with Windows .efi files matches grub's boot stanza UUID. `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -af |grep -sv loop`  (excludes snaps).

Comment: I turned off fast start up in windows now. The UUID is correct i double checked that. I already have the newest version of the bios for my mobo. I tried to change efi to EFI in /boot/grub/grub.cfg. The problem is still not solved. The thing is if I get the error message in grub i can just reboot and press DEL to go in my BIOS and than exit without doing anything. Than I can select windows again in grub and than it boots it like it normally would. So I really dont know what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: In FAT32 case does not matter, so EFI is same as efi. In Linux formatted partitions case does matter. Do you have more than one ESP - efi system partition with Windows boot files? Again need to see fstab & lsblk outputs.

Comment: I put the outputs in the question. I am pretty sure i have one efi partition with windows boot file.

Comment: then this partition/UUID does not exist as it says: "error: no such device: EC4C-105C". So where is that coming from. Look in this for any mention of that UUID:  `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `sudo nano  /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: OMG Im sorry i reinstalled ubuntu and linux which probably changed the UUID. I edited the question with the correct error UUID showing in the error now. 

This is in that file for windows:
```menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme1n1p2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-6E4E-A0AB' {
 insmod part_gpt
 insmod fat
 if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  6E4E-A0AB
 else
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6E4E-A0AB
 fi
 chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Comment: Better to post in question as then you can preserve formatting. Not easy to read in a comment. But with correct UUID, does it now work? Many have installed a second Linux and swap gets reformatted with new UUID & first install does not boot. UUID should not change, but reformatting will change them.

Comment: It also looks as if you swapped the two nvme-drives in their slots, from `update-grub`-output in your question it is `/dev/nvme0n1p2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` but the partition with the matching UUID is  `/dev/nvme1n1p2` in the `lsblk`-output.

Comment: I reinstalled windows and ubuntu a couple times. The last time was following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives) and now the issue with grub is solved. I want to thank you guys for helping me