# Problems with Dual SSD Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ssd

Yesterday I bought a new SSD to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on it. I already had an SSD with Windows 10 on it in the PC.

I followed this guide on how to install Ubuntu: [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

After Ubuntu installation, the dual boot menu does not show up, the login screen on Ubuntu is slow, my mouse cursor seems to be lagging and dragging, almost impossible to use. Whenever I type my password, it is stuck on a infinite loop, asking me to type again.

I'm a beginner and don't know what to do. How do I troubleshoot this?

EDIT:

SSD is set to GPT

I did install using UEFI.

Specs:

```
Mobo: [Gigabyte Z370-M][1]   
CPU: Intel i5 8400  
RAM: 16 GB  
GPU: RTX 2060   
Drives:    
/dev/sda Samsung SSD 240 gb for Windows   
/dev/sdb 2TB HDD used for storage   
/dev/sdc 256 GB SSD for Ubuntu
```

I  subsequently installed PopOS; it seems to be working fine, just Grub doesn't detect Windows.

Here are the results of *parted -l* :

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  577MB  576MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      577MB   250GB  249GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA ST2000DM006-2DM1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs         boot


Model: ATA GIGABYTE GP-GSTF (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name      Flags
 1      2097kB  524MB   522MB   fat32                     boot, esp
 2      524MB   4819MB  4295MB  fat32           recovery  msftdata
 3      4819MB  252GB   247GB   ext4
 4      252GB   256GB   4295MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap: 4294MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  4294MB  4294MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

[Rufus Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZec0.png)

Whenever I tried to built the boot drive selecting GPT, it was frozen on loading, requiring me to restart the system. The only work around I found was setting it to MBR.

Comment: What brand, model system? What video card/chip? Is Windows installed in UEFI boot mode. Have you updated UEFI for system and SSD firmware?

Comment: SSD Gigabyte 256GB 2.5" Sata III 6GB/s, GP-GSTFS31256GTND, Intel i5 8400, Nvidia RTX 2060, the ssd is brand new, and I don't know if the UEFI for the system is updated.

Comment: @ZephSenpai Looks like your Windows 10 is on a MBR formatted drive, which suggests a legacy boot system, whereas your Linux is installed on GPT drivers, which is used by EFI.

Answer (score 1):

You should install GRUB onto the same device where the windows bootloader lies, so that you can change between systems. GRUB (especially recent versions) know well to handle Windows 10. Which version of Ubuntu are you installing? Is it an MBR (old style) or UEFI installation?