# Install Ubuntu and Windows in different drives of same computer

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Some backstory (TLDR: skip to next paragraph). I am a novice linux user, but have been using Ubuntu for quite a while now for my daily tasks. My current laptop of 10 years gave up and now its CPU is always on 80-85% usage on start up. It lags a lot and I am not able to run anything smoothly. Also it randomly restarts. Tried reinstalling Ubuntu, same problem. I think there is some problem in the CPU. We have an "extended family computer"(not mine and it runs windows 10 PRO) which has an M.2 SSD slot free. My plan is to use that one for some months, till I buy a new PC.

### What I want to achieve

1. Install Ubuntu in the M.2 SSD without modifying anything on the computer.
2. The PC should by default boot into Windows, like it does always.(I am not the owner of that PC). This is mandatory as I don't want GRUB to take over.
3. When I want to use the said computer, I will go to BIOS menu and select the SSD to boot from it. So that I will only use my ubuntu installation.
4. Virtual Machine is not an option as I do not want to boot into windows at all.

Not sure if this is helpful, but these are the system specs;

CPU - i5 7400

Mobo - ASUS B250

RAM - 8 GB

Most tutorials I find, replaces the default boot loader, which i do not want. So asking here for help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think without Grub, you would not only need to alter the boot order before booting Ubuntu, but also to restore the boot order after you're done. With Grub, however, you would see a single unfamiliar screen for a few seconds before Windows boots automatically. Your extended family may not object to that, or even notice it. During these seconds you would have the chance to choose Ubuntu rather than the default, Windows.

Comment: @jos Is it possible to make grub directly boot into windows without that screen and let me choose ubuntu when I want? For example; I press some key at boot and it lets me choose. If not, it should behave like it does not exist,

Comment: No, you can't bypass that screen entirely, but you can reduce the time it's shown to 3 seconds, perhaps even 1 second. To do that, you need to manually change the `grub` configuration or use [this tool](https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like that you know how to install Ubuntu in a separate SSD? If not read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245743/1073514).

You can skip Grub entirely by moving it bellow Windows boot manager in Firmware settings. You will find this in boot sequence. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. It boots into windows by default and when I want to use ubuntu I just press F8 and select from there.

Comment: Nice. Good to know it worked. Have a great time with Ubuntu.