# Does my Windows on a separate ssd get affected if I messed up in Linux while dual booting?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, 20.04, ssd

I want to dual boot my PC with Windows 10 (already installed) and Ubuntu 20.04.

My Windows is installed on a separate ssd (which is my complete my C drive). I am installing the Ubuntu on my hdd using the "Something else" pathway.

My concern is that if something goes wrong while installing Ubuntu, will my Windows system stay safe on my ssd?

I have my important data backed up anyways ;)

Comment: It depends on what you will do while installing Ubuntu. For example, you can select the Windows disk by a mistake. But generally all should be OK.

Comment: It is possible to delete my Windows on my SSD from Ubuntu. It also qualifies as a fatal error. So the answer is yes. Keep a backup at hand.

Comment: You can mess up your EFI partition. Read this and you should be fine. Tell me whether it worked. https://askubuntu.com/a/1245770/1073514

Comment: @SasukeUchiha It's an awesome answer! Just wanted to confirm something. When you created a new efi partition in your HDD, you still had the original efi partition in the SSD, with the original Windows Bootloader? How does the system decide which efi file to load?

Comment: @aymusbond When you select it from the grub menu... Your windows boot files are stored in the ssd and ubuntu boot files (grub) are stored in the hdd. You can select which one to boot from grub menu

Comment: @aymusbond If it was useful to you, please [upvote](//$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) that answer for future readers.

Comment: Done :) I was just got my upvoting rights.