# Dual boot in windows 10 with unallocated disk space

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am facing a few concerns while trying to install my first Linux along with my windows 10. My windows have three disks C: D: and E:. Now I want to install Linux into the D: drive as that only has the free storage.

I shrunk the free storage in D: and made it unallocated to be specific I have unallocated 25gb space.

Now I have got the latest ubuntu-20.04 and used Rufus to make a bootable pen drive.

While making the bootable pen drive I got a warning from Rufus saying this is a hybrid image so ISO and dd methods are possible.

It mentioned ISO is recommended so I went with it and made the bootable pen drive ready.

My concern if I use this pen drive now to install will Linux installation automatically assign the unallocated space for installation?, if something goes bad during installation will all my files in other drives C: D: and E: of windows be wiped? I want to figure out a way where even though if the installation is messed up nothing happens to the other drives as I don't have any ways to backup the data for now. Please help me out guys thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have a backup of all important files, presumably what you call " other drives". There is never any way to guarantee that nothing will happen. Also, no, the installer will not assign unallocated space automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to get that warning about Hybrid Image. You will know if you read [Offical Tutorial on creating bootable USB with Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#8-write-warnings).

It can most certainly mess up if you do not do it properly. So like mikewatever said it is better to have backups and the installation wizard will not assign the free space automatically.

But you should be fine if you choose the **Something Else** option during installation. You can read [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247090/how-to-install-ubuntu-while-keeping-my-files-backup-disk-partition-i-made-with/1247118#1247118) to get an idea how to do this. You will be fine with only th `/` partition. Select the free space and press the `+` button to create this.