# How to boot Ubuntu when stuck on line dev/sdaX: clean, XX/XX files, XX/XX blocks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

When booting my Ubuntu after a fresh install, after I select Ubuntu from the grub menu, it starts booting and then it stop with just this one line:

```
dev/sdaX: clean, XX/XX files, XX/XX blocks
```

I installed it allong a working Windows 10 that has it's own EFI boot partition, and so Linux uses the same one to install Grub I think.

Comment: That is most likely a failing hard drive.  You can try to repair it with Gparted and making new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the problem. The first solution might be required, but it might be worth testing if you have the same problem.

- I reinstalled Ubuntu following this answer to create a second EFI part for my Linux to boot independently from Windows: https://askubuntu.com/a/843649 I also disabled fastboot and secure boot previously as said in this answer
- I realized that I could only start my live version with the (safe graphics) option. Found that it starts thanks to a grub option named `nomodeset`. I then followed this answer to finally be able to boot by setting the grub `nomodeset` option manually: https://askubuntu.com/a/38834
- Once finally on my booted Ubuntu, I followed this answer so that it will always boot with the `nomodeset` option enabled: https://askubuntu.com/a/38782/841934

Hope this will help some people, at least me when I maybe will encounter the problem again in some months/years.

**EDIT**: as said by heynnema the nomodeset solution was only a temporary fix. What I did next was update my NVIDIA graphic drivers by following the graphical method of this guide:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux
I then reverted my changes to my grub config to remove the nomodeset option, and rebooted without problem.

Comment: That's not the right solution. nomodeset effectively disables the video driver, and amongst other problems, you probably won't be able to set your monitor resolution. nomodeset is only used for testing purposes. You probably need to update/install a video driver.