# Delete 1 EFI partition from the 2 I have

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, uninstall

**Situation:** Okey, y recently installed Ubuntu on my computer, I wanna have a dual boot machine with Windows and Ubuntu with 2 hard drives, I have a couple of issues with grub which doesn't show the selection OS menu. So I followed [This installation guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives) there someone recomended than during the installation process create an *"EFI/ partition"* and select it as *"device for boot loader installation"*.

I wasn't aware of what I was actually doing, but that doensn't solve my problem. I solve it by rebuilding Grub with `grub-install`. At present, I uninstalled ubuntu partitions but...

[Here, how the partitions end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09xiv.png)

**Question:** Now I realize that what I did was create another UEFI partition (I read that the System just use 1, so I want to delete the one that is remaining safely, so:

- Wich one delete?
- How to delete it safely?

Comment: It's OK to have an EFI on each device.  That would allow the device to be moved and still boot on a new machine.  However the Ubuntu installer just puts its files on the first EFI it sees (sda1 probably) see launchpad bugs 1396379,1173457.  The EFI partition on your second disk is probably empty, so that's the one to delete.

Comment: From Win 10 make sure that ['Fast Start'](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/) is disabled. Delete The 572 MB EFI partition you made on disk 1, then install Mint on that disk, following [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/) from **step 5**.

Comment: @ubfan1 is right. It’s fine to have an EFI partition on both drives. You haven’t said if your system is booting correctly. I assume it is. You can check which EFI partition is in use by Ubuntu with the lsblk command. If it’s using the one on Disco 0 and the one you created is empty you can delete the partition on Disco 1. I have configured my machine so that the original Windows EFI partition boots just Windows while the EFI partition on the second drive can boot either. As ubfan1 says that makes it possible to move disks between machines

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right I just delete the second EFI partition and everything was all righ.