# Dual booting on startup I get a completely black screen and need to enter BIOS then exit in order to get to GNU GRUB. How do I fix this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, amd-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 on a separate SSD from my Windows installation. I followed [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/843649/1177352) for how to do that . When I boot up my computer I see a black screen and it stays like that. In order to boot I must enter BIOS and when I exit BIOS it will go to GNU GRUB OS selection screen and let me choose which OS to boot. Both Windows and Ubuntu then boot fine.

My system does use UEFI and I have secure boot disabled. Before I had secure boot disabled, and on a previous installation of Ubuntu (tried reinstalling a few times), when I turned on my computer it would go to a GNU GRUB command line terminal. I am curious if it is going to that same terminal but maybe isn't displaying anything? Anyways, I've been searching online for this issue and haven't found anything yet. My GPU is AMD ATI Radeon RX 5600 if that matters.

edit: I did run `sudo update-grub`, restarted and it went into GNU GRUB and let me select OS. Any restart after that still had the same issue. When I ran that command again an restarted I am still getting the black screen.

edit: I am on an HP OMEN 25L Desktop GT12-0xxx for reference. When I boot my computer, I get a completely black screen and my monitor then begins cycling through inputs as I'm guessing it isn't getting anything. It stays like this indefinitely so I restart my computer again pressing F10 to enter UEFI where both Windows and Ubuntu are configured in UEFI mode with Ubuntu listed first. Once I exit UEFI, I am taken to the GNU GRUB boot selector screen where I can chose between Windows or Ubuntu. This is the screen that I would expect on boot up without having to enter UEFI first.

edit: Here is what my drives look like in `gparted`:

Ubunutu drive:
[image: Ubunutu drive]
Windows drive:
[image: Windows drive]
Windows storage drive:
[image: Windows storage drive]

edit: Output from `sudo efibootmgr`:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0003* ubuntu
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you have both installed in the same boot mode. Also check whether ubuntu is first in UEFI firmware settings (BIOS settings make sure you are in UEFI only mode) boot order.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what same boot mode means. I do have have Ubuntu as first OS in the boot order and I have legacy BIOS disabled so this is in UEFI.

Comment: By same boot mode I meant both in UEFI. So what can you give me more details of what exactly happens when you power on you computer. It might be also useful to know about your system. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1312360/edit) your question and add this info

Comment: Could you share yoiur gparted output for all drived? Partition - File Systek - Mount Point - Size

Comment: Sometimes there is a key to press to choose the "BIOS" boot menu, which will then let you select the disk to load, often it's F12. If that works and you get the Grub menu then it could be you installed Grub to Linux partition instead of to the disk root. But I confess UEFI is a mystery to me. `sudo efibootmgr` output might help.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I updated screenshots of my drives in gparted. Let me know if that info helps or there is anything else I can add.

Comment: @pbhj I added the output to that command in the post. I'll try the F12 and see what happens. I'm not sure how Grub is installed but I thought I had set everything up correctly. Maybe from my screenshots it's possible to tell?

Comment: You seem to have selected the Windows EFI partition as the bootloader location for grub. give me the output of ls /boot/efi

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced that Ubuntu was instlaled in EUFI mode. Open a terminal and type this `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode" `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have selected the Windows EFI partition as the bootloader location for grub during install.

1. Boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdc`
2. Make a backup of fstab (`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`
3. Find  and copy the UUID of the Ubuntu EFI partition using `sudo blkid`
4. Run `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and replace the UUID of the partition with the mountpoint /boot/efi with the UUID you copied.
5. Run `sudo umount /boot/efi`
6. Run `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /boot/efi`
7. Run `sudo update-grub`
8. Reboot.

Comment: Ubuntu is already at the top of the list for my boot order in BIOS. My UEFI firmware settings doesn't have a boot order, just a page that lets you enter the different boots.

Comment: @yak updated the answer with the new info you provided.

Comment: It works, believe it! Thank you. For some reason I had to do it twice though, maybe because the first time I shut down my PC instead of restart? Also it brought me to the GNU grub command prompt, and I had to type `exit` to get top the OS selector screen. Now it goes straight to the OS selector screen.

Comment: Happy to help...

Comment: Dude... Did you not offer the bounty?

Comment: Sorry! I'm new to that feature and I thought that accepting the answer would automatically offer the bounty. I'll see if I can get it offered.