# BIOS needs resetting after each boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, uefi

I performed a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my PC in the dual boot configuration using UEFI mode. I used the "Something else..." option during disk selection and followed this tutorial, [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation), on how to do it.

Windows is installed on a separate SSD. Installation was successful, but after a restart the PC didn't boot and I was not able to access BIOS/UEFI. After clearing the CMOS, and setting the boot order manually to use Ubuntu, GRUB was showing both operating systems and Ubuntu worked normally.

However, after each restart, I have to reset BIOS settings and set boot order for PC to boot at all.

- I disabled secure boot in UEFI and disabled fast boot in Windows.
- I already tried reinstalling Ubuntu 3 times, but each time I had similar problems.
- I also tried using Boot-Repair tool, but it didn't help,

I have an MSI X570 ACE motherboard and Nvidia RTX 2070 SUPER GPU.

This [Boot-info summary report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fbcTF48pkB/) was generated after another reinstall, where I tried using different partitioning schema using this tutorial: [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives).

I had to set this boot order, so that I would be able to boot using Ubuntu from a USB drive. I did not update either SSD firmware or UEFI. I installed nVidia drivers by clicking install additional drivers during OS installation. I set swap partition as big because i have 32GB of RAM, and I read that it is supposed to be bigger that my memory size. When I set boot order in a way you describe I am able to boot to Ubuntu and everything works flawlessly, but after reboot I am not able to do anything and have to reset BIOS settings to use my PC.

I performed a reset with the Ubuntu power-off option. When I booted Windows from GRUB everything worked well, so what is causing the issue is the booting of Ubuntu itself. I tried finding "fast boot" in MSI UEFI but I did not find it anywhere. According to [this Polish website](https://forum.benchmark.pl/topic/282162-brak-opcji-fast-boot-w-msi-b450/) (there is also a screenshot included), there is no fast boot option in MB for Ryzen CPUs. I was thinking about trying to install a different distro and checking if it would work properly.

What else could I do?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be UEFI settings, but to confirm boot: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: UEFI boot order still set to drive, see line 132. You want default to be Ubuntu or `sudo efibootmgr -o 4,3,5,6` If efibootmgr does not work use your UEFI settings tab and change  boot order (not UEFI boot menu). Have you updated UEFI? Updated SSD firmware? Did you install nVidia drivers as part of Ubuntu install? You need those from Ubuntu repository. See also  `man efibootmgr`  and
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr Installer now uses swap file, so swap partition not required, but will be used if you have one. And swap does not need to be that large.

Comment: Not sure what is happening that a reboot causes issues. Is that a warm reboot or a full "cold" reboot or power shutdown & drain system. If  you have "fast boot" which is different from Windows "fast start up" set in UEFI, it assumes no system hardware or configuration change. So info UEFI writes to drive is back to previous boot. Microsoft requires boot fast settings, to make it seem like Windows boots faster. Hibernation typically not  recommended when dual booting, so swap over 2 or 4GB suggested. I think default swap file with new installs is 2GB.

Comment: I do not know MSI, but looked at manual. I would review these settings:  (may be related to fast boot? Full Screen Logo Display [Enabled]
  I would use UEFI only: Boot Mode Select [LEGACY+UEFI]
 Check this: FIXED BOOT ORDER Priorities
 And then this: Boot Option Priorities  Some UEFI/Windows sync UEFI & Windows BCD settings, so users add a BCD entry.  See last lines in Boot-Repair summary.  In Windows: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
undo:
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` Grub only boots working Windows, have Windows repair flash drive.

Comment: @oldfred I finally managed to make it work... After another reinstall, where I selected the whole drive for the boot device not only a single partition, and after setting UEFI to LEGACY+UEFI.

Comment: Please post your last comment as an answer, and mark it as accepted, in order to remove your question from the unanswered queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oldfred I finally managed to make it work... After another reinstall, where I selected the whole drive for the boot device not only a single partition, and after setting UEFI to LEGACY+UEFI.