# Will Ubuntu 20.04 lts support my Z590 mother board?

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, shutdown

my current issue is that every time I boot into ubuntu, it shuts down immediately and restarts again itself. It goes into a loop.

I am trying to boot into Ubuntu 20.04. (I use the safe graphics install to install Ubuntu 20.04 to my Samsung 980 pro nvm SSD card)

The only interface that the computer does not shut down is the GRUB.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this strange thing?

The following are the only things that are set up in my computer build right now:

- Motherboard: Z590 MSI PRO WIFI
- CPU: i9-10850k and a CPU fan
- RAM: one 16 gb 3600MHZ, 18
- M2: Samsung 980 Pro NVMe
- power supply: EVGA 700 GD, 80+ GOLD 700W

@ChanganAuto and @oldfred Thank you for the suggestions.

Currently, What I have tried which can log into the OS and even the user interface is edit the Ubuntu option in GRUB. However, only before 5 minutes the computer shuts down itself.

Specifically, I added "$vt_handoff nomodeset". When loading, I found that it keeps saying that `Bluetooth hc10: reading intel version information failed (-22)`

Comment: What do you mean by boot into? Is it installed? Are you trying to boot from live media?

Comment: @David. I was successfully used USB drive to install Ubuntu 20.04 using safe graphics mode (install to my ssd card). But I cannot boot into the ssd (with the installed Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @David I also tried to boot into the USB drive and go to GRUB mode. I cannot use the first option but only safe graphics mode(that's why I use safe graphics mode to install).

Comment: You are booting in safe graphics mode on the installed version?

Comment: @David I also have another USB drive that containing ubuntu 18 version. I try to boot into this usb drive and use the "try ubuntu". I cannot get in as well.

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 18 also you make no mention of video card in the hardware listed.

Comment: @David. I think there is no safe graphics mode on the installed version.. Only the usb drive containing the Ubuntu 20.04 installer has safe graphics mode.

Comment: No all version can be started in nomodeset you need to tell grub to use it by interrupting the startup

Comment: @David Ubuntu Sorry for the confusion. I mean 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver).  The video card is the integrated video card from CPU: Intel® UHD Graphics 630

Comment: So, the next question is: Have you installed in UEFI mode? You should. Then, have you updated the UEFI and the SSD's firmware? I suppose not so please start with that. Then some changes to the UEFI settings maybe needed.

Comment: In addition to updates, you need to go newer not older. Intel releases updates to kernels & drivers. Then they get included into distributions. But all that takes some time and changes are not normally back ported to older installs. You need newest available distribution and maybe even the soon to be released 21.04. May be similar? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317921/bios-needs-resetting-after-each-boot

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for the suggestion. not sure how to updated the SSD's firmware but I definitely try install Ubuntu in UEFI mode in my next next. Currently, I added "$vt_handoff nomodeset" in the grub mode. When loading, I found that it keeps saying that Bluetooth hc10: reading intel version information failed (-22).

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for the suggestion. I tried once without any CPU fan. Then I go into BIOS, the cpu temperature shows ~100 celsius degrees. With the CPU fan installed as well as the thermal paste on, I go into BIOS and the CPU is around 35 celsius degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

It seems that there are extra steps that finally make my new computer boot successfully. Here is how I solved this issue completely (I hope).

1. buy a new power supply. I bet the original one is defective which may explain it shuts down immediately after post/grub every time.
2. In the Grub mode, I modified the argument by adding `nomodeset` at the end of the lien of `linux` argument.

One may search for `nomodeset` via google to see related information. As a matter of fact, the safe graphic mode for installation includes `nomodeset`.

See reference: [Black screen after installation of Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04)

3. After I successfully installed (using safe graphic mode) and use `nomodeset` argument when boot in, Wifi and Bluetooth cannot use. And I donot want to use `nomodeset` every time.  Fortunately I have Ethernet cable. I follow this link https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=346412 and install `linux-oem-20.04b` via `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b` in the terminal.

From install to complete:

1. in Grub mode use safe graphic mode to install.
2. When boot into the installed Ubuntu, add `nomodeset`.
3. Open terminal and enter `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b`.