# Erase disk install option

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I’ve got windows installed on an nvme drive and I have a sata ssd that I want to install Ubuntu on without wiping out the windows drive. Can I use the “Erase disk and install Ubuntu” option? Or will this destroy my other drives?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently actually. It depends on which drive it's referring to. I would be safe and use the option "Something else" where you can set the drive to install to manually. Otherwise, it will assume you want to install to the nvme.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just make absolutely sure that you are installing Ubuntu to your SATA SSD, or else it will wipe out your Windows installation.