# Boot both windows 10 and ubuntu on SSD while user files on HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot

What I want is similar to [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives), but what I want is both windows 10 and ubuntu boot on SSD while the ubuntu user files like /home will be stored on HDD.

Can I follow the instruction on the link provided above, but make partition on SSD for ubuntu /EFI instead on HDD?

Windows 10 is already installed on my SSD.

I'm no experience in installing linux or let alone setting up a dual boot, If you guys can provide an instructions that are more appropriate or updated(I noticed it 6 years old, not saying that the instructions are obsolete just I have no idea but eager to learn), please do it will be much appecriated.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely doable. Basically you just need to forget about Windows and follow this detailed guide to move your home to HDD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Only one ESP - efi system partition per drive. Ubuntu will use the existing ESP on SSD. You can put /home on HDD, but that cannot be seen from Windows as it must be Linux format. I keep /home inside / on SSD but have data partitions on HDD. Back with XP I had both Linux & NTFS partitions for data. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: You will probably want your HDD to support Linux style files (permissions, case sensitive, length). However, Windows doesn’t always work with Linux file system types. FAT32 is very limited, and both FAT32 and NTFS will have permission issues in Linux. There are some free and paid Windows ext4 drivers available. If you can get ext4 to work in Windows, I would suggest using ext4 on your HDD.