# Getting Top Bar Black Screen when changing refresh rate - Dual Boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, display, gpu

I setup a dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04, using this [instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/843649/1598268) but I create partition for ESP or `/EFI` on SSD(which where windows 10 also installed) and mount the `/` root directory on a separate partition in HDD, I didn't create additional partition for the `/swap` and `/home`.

Everything seem okay, the grub menu shows which allows me to boot either ubuntu or windows, but I noticed when I booting ubuntu, I get this Timeout Error but the boot process will still continue bringing me to login display:

[image: Timeout Error image]

The most noticeable issue is when I getting "Top Bar Blackscreen" on my monitor after changing the monitor refresh rate from 60hz to 165hz, because my monitor supports 165hz:

[image: Top Bar Blackscreen image]

When I change back the refresh rate to 60hz, the "blackscreen" disappear but I want to set it to 165hz because the display movement seem slow. I don't know if the error I getting from booting is related to the blackscreen when the refresh rate is not on 60hz and could it be the video driver isn't compatible?

I'm still beginner in linux and terminal, so if you can provide a set of instructions that can be follow by a beginner mind it will be very welcome one but any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You tagged "Nvidia" so supposedly that's your graphics card? If so do you have the Nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: I trying to install the nvidia driver, but I find these four "types" of drivers to choose from, **nvidia metapackage**, **nvidia headless metapackage**, **nvidia headless metapackage no dkms** and **nvidia xorg**. I don't know which one I should choose

Comment: So you didn't select the option to install 3rd party **drivers**, firmware, codecs, etc. when you installed Ubuntu? The installer would have done it automatically for you and select the best driver. The latest version is usually the best option (there are exceptions).

Comment: I choose **nvidia metapackage**, it seems working now and fix the Top bar Blackscreen but still getting the timeout error. Yes I didn't select the option to install 3rd party software because when Installing ubuntu for dual boot setup I also following this [instruction](https://itsfoss.com/dual-boot-hdd-ssd/) and it says that to uncheck the option, this is my mistake.

Comment: In this day and age there's no good reason not to select that option. Here's why: (1) (proprietary) Drivers you usually need so it's a lot easier to install alongside everything else; (2) ditto for firmware even if not needed for your current hardware. Later when you intend to use some peripheral you won't have to troubleshoot; (3) additional media codecs you don't need but want, otherwise you'll have to install them anyway when the weird video you were sent doesn't play..

Comment: Hmm, is there is anyway to install those 3rd party softwares after installation of ubuntu? in my quick search I found `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`, is this enough?

Comment: Not for drivers, only codecs and fonts as explained in the answer to your other question. The proprietary drivers you already installed in Additional Drivers.