# How can I install Ubuntu on one drive without causing data loss on another drive?

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 128 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD which has 4 partitions containing a lot of data.

After installing Ubuntu, can I use my 1 TB HDD the same as before?

Will my data will lost after installing Ubuntu?

How do I cleanly install Ubuntu on the SSD without causing any data loss on the HDD?

Comment: Are you asking about a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: If you have to ask question, I assume you do not have good backups. That is the first step. And know which drive is which with Ubuntu, not Windows info. And partition in advance with gparted and only use Something Else install option to choose partition(s) you created for /, & ESP - efi system partition. That assumes Windows is UEFI as you want Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drive also.http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives

Comment: I've come to enjoy using Linux in virtual machines. You don't need to reboot to access your other OS's, run them side-by-side.

Answer (score 2):

That totally depends on what you choose during installation.

Generally I would advice to pick "something else", select the sdd for mountpoint `/` and select the hdd, and give it a mountpoint for each of the 4 partitions you want to keep and add to the new system, and pick the filesystem it currently has WITHOUT formatting.  After install you need to do `sudo chown $USER:$USER /{mountpoint{1-4}}`

Mind that if there is an OS (ie. Windows) on the hdd it now becomes a data partition in your new system. This will erase anything on the ssd and make it a bootable Ubuntu where the hdd is a storage partition. It will be a SINGLE boot.

Mind that you need to make a backup of anything important. Always, reguraly. Not just when you mess with partitions.

Comment: According to OP question, HDD has 4 partitions, so 4 separate mountpoints for each of the partitions will be required.

Comment: @raj good catch :)