# Grub error while dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have been dual booting for a while with no problems. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

When Ubuntu decided to not work, I reinstalled it, and everything went well. I then went to load up Windows, and got the following error:

```
error: no such device
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

I have searched online for what to do here, but nothing appears to be exactly my situation, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Also, a lot of the answers I see tell you to start typing in some commands, but don't really explain what is going on, so I don't know whether it applies to me or not. I know literally nothing about grub other than it helps to boot the OS, and am not interested in learning about it for this one thing.

Is there anyone who can help please?

Comment: Best to know details, before randomly typing commands. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Did you click on the link?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realise you were asking me to click a link. I think this is what you were asking me to do: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pRKFknMztN/

Comment: You now have two different boot modes. Windows is BIOS on MBR and Ubuntu is UEFI on gpt. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. So did you install Windows? You have to reinstall Windows boot loader to boot Windows in BIOS mode, It looks like if you turn on UEFI boot, Ubuntu may boot, but BIOS grub now in MBR will not work unless you convert Ubuntu to BIOS boot mode. Best to reinstall Windows. You can have two boot modes only because each is on separate drive, but may have to change UEFI settings each time you switch.

Comment: OK. I didn't understand a word of what you said except 'reinstall Windows', so I'll try that.

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS from live installer is then how it installs. You have to choose a UEFI:XXX option. That is independant of default boot mode which is for installed systems. Installing Windows may erase some or all of Ubuntu so make sure you  have good backups. Windows will create these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives